# Sending data out a network interface programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, network-programming

I have a port query application that checks a remote port to see if it is open or blocked. What I want to do is when doing the port check, the ability to select which network interface on my local machine to send the traffic out of. Is this possible and how would I do so?

Update:

I have added the following lines and it is still not binding

```
    string localip; 
    localip = interfacesComboBox.Text; 
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000; 
IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(localip); 
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(myIP, 0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private ushort BindToNextAvail(Socket sock, params ushort[] portList)
    {
        foreach (ushort i in portList)
        {
            try
            {
                sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, i));
                return (ushort)((IPEndPoint)sock.LocalEndPoint).Port;
            }
            catch
            {
                Logger.Instance().WriteLog(EventLogEntryType.Warning, "Unable to use port " + i.ToString());
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

That is from my live application so it should roughly work for you.

And an example of where the method is called:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

if (Bind(socket, 10000, 10001, 10002) == 0)
    throw new SocketException(10049); // "Cannot assign requested address" exception
```

Comment: ...most of this code is redundant. All he needs to do to bind to a specific interface is `.Bind(new IPEndPoint(addresOfEndpoint, 0))`. `0` makes the system choose an available port automatically.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - While that may be true, this code will optionally allow the user to specify a series of ports that **THEY** want to be bound to. Not necessarily a requirement but it works well in my application.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, I have tried your method:

but it is not working, it is still sending it out my Ethernet interface and not my WiFi

            `string localip;
            localip = interfacesComboBox.Text;

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

            IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(localip);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(myIP, 0));`

Comment: @KPS - If you bind to IPAddress.Any then Windows will base which interface your packet goes out on based on the route-ability of your network interface. (e.g. A packet destined for 192.168.1.6 will go out of the interface on the 192.168.1.0 network). It is a little more sophisticated than that but hopefully that helps describe how it works.

Comment: Guys, sorry it was my mistake. I created a new socket when I did not need it...it is now working! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using sockets, call the [Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) method before connecting. It allows you to specify the network interface to use by specifying the IP of the local endpoint.